# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow'

Tags: google-sheets

Hey guys i have a problem with this i found on yt, can someone help me. it is for a school exam. it is the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow'". (Last line)

```js
//Funktion til at sende dataen til databasen

function sumitData(){

  //Set refearancen til aktivt google sheets

  var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Søg i databasen");

  var datasheet=myGoogleSheet.getRangeByName("Database");

  //Funktion til at udnytte alarm funktionen

  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var response=ui.alert("Insend", "Vil du insende dataen?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  //Funktion til at chekke for bruger respons

  if(response==ui.Button.NO){

  //Funktion til at sende brugeren tilbage
    return;
}

if(validateEntry()==true){
  var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1;
}
```

Comment: What did you find on YT ? What is your goal here ?

Comment: I want to make a simple database, i can send the full code if you think thats bettere

Comment: It is this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-Io0Y59nYA

Answer (score 0):

Because `datasheet` is not a sheet in your script, modifiy as follows

```
var datasheet=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Database");
```